# Undefined query in Nest.js

Tags: nestjs, objectid

I'm working with mongo and nest. In my code, there are multiple endpoints where I have a query that must allow values as ObjectId or undefined. For example:

```js
@Get()
findAll(
  @Query('foreignId', ObjectIdPipe) foreignId?: Types.ObjectId | undefined,
) {
  console.log(foreignId); // Always logs an ObjectId
  return this.booksService.findBooks({ ) });
}

@Injectable()
export class ObjectIdPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    console.log("Original value:", value);
    if (value && isObjectIdOrHexString(value)) {
      return new Types.ObjectId(value);
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }
  }
}
```

The pipe works when the request has an explicitly null, undefined or empty value for `foreignId`, but it doesn't work if `foreignId` is not present.

Comment: how your request looks like on all scenarios?

Comment: It has other query parameters, but even though it doesn't work. I'm observing if I change the type of the parameter to @Query('foreignId', ObjectIdPipe) foreignId?: Types.ObjectId | string, it works when the foreignId isn't provided. I don't know why it works, but I would prefer another solution because if the provided string isn't an ObjectId, I want to return an BadRequestException.

Comment: The `ObjectIdPipe` you are using, pass `{ optional: true }` inside that as constructor

Comment: I'm trying, but it doesn't work, how should I receive it in the constructor? because my ObjectIdPipe class doesn't have a constructor.